# how to remove active record object from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have set of active record object in array.

I just want to delete on object from array not in database

```
a = Model.limit(2)

b = Model.first

a.delete(b)
```

returning nil value

Its not deleting

is there anyway?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
a.to_a - [b]
```

Background: `a.to_a` convertrs the relation into an array in in memory.
`[b]` is an array whith just the element, you want to delete (in memory).
`a.to_a - [b]` does an array substraction.

(In Rails 3.2 .to_a was applied automatically to a relation when it was accessed. I agree with `gregates`: It's better to convert the relation to an array explicitly)

Answer (score 15):

There's potentially some confusion here because in `ActiveRecord`, `Model.limit(2)` does not return an array.

```
Model.limit(2).class #=> ActiveRecordRelation
```

So when you call `a.delete(b)`, you may not be calling `Array#delete`.

Try this instead:

```
a = Model.limit(2).to_a # Executes the query and returns an array
b = Model.first
a.delete(b)
```

Comment: nice idea to use `all` to get an array out of the relation. I tried and `to_a` works as well and might be a fraction more explicit.

Comment: `all` does not return an array anymore in Rails 4.2, `to_a` does.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
objects_in_db = Model.all
objects_in_array = Model.first(2)
objects_in_array.delete_if { |obj| !objects_in_db.include?(obj)}
```

In your case, `Model.limit(2)` may not return the first two object and so the array `a` may not contain `b` and hence, it returns `nil`.

Comment: i can see the matching object is avail in b

Comment: can you provide your model's structure?. Try with some other model and see if there is any problem with your model.